# How to use Born approximation with degeneracy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, scattering, approximations

According to the scattering theory, the scattering state wave function $|\psi_l\rangle$ follows the Lippmann-Schwinger equation. If we take the first order Born approximation,then
$$
|\psi_l\rangle=|l\rangle+\sum_{l'}\frac{V_{l',l}}{\varepsilon_l-\varepsilon_{l'}+i\delta}|l'\rangle
$$
the expectation of operator $A$ of scattering state is
$$
\langle A\rangle\approx\langle l|A|l\rangle+2Re\Big[\sum_{l'}\frac{A_{l,l'}V_{l',l}}{\varepsilon_l-\varepsilon_{l'}+i\delta}\Big]
$$
If $\varepsilon_l=\varepsilon_{l'}$, the second term will be divergent when one takes $\delta\to 0$. Therefore, I can only deal with this problem as we do with degenerate perturbation. How to use Born approximation to calculate the expectation of operator $A$?

Comment: The numerator could help compensate the cancellation of the denominator. Do you have a specific example of $A$ in mind ?

Comment: If the element of $A$ is pure imaginary number, the real part of the second term will have Dirac delta function form, then the summation of wave vector k will not be divergent. But the element of $A$ can be real, then the denominator of real part of second term will not be Dirac delta form. If I summarize the wave vector k, the summation will be divergent in the case of continuous spectrum. I don’t know how to deal with the divergence.

Comment: Usually it’s not a sum but rather an integral. In general, the $i\delta$ prescription is telling to take the Cauchy principal value. But as I said before, if the numerator cancels, you could also just have a removable singularity.